# Using Jinja2, is it possible to disable a tag and/or filter?

Tags: templates, jinja2

I have templates that are saved in a database (my clients will create them). I don't want my clients to be able to extend their templates (I know, I know, that's srsly evil). I do want them to be able to include snippets, but not extend templates. How can I disable or remove the `{% extends %}` tag, and also how can I remove filters, if I later choose to do that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the templates are saved in the database, you must be able to filter the extends before the save.

Comment: Messing with the source code of the templates is unreliable and looks like input sanitizing, albeit on a different level of input.

Comment: You do not have to mess with the source code. You can inform the user : extends not allowed and block te save.

Comment: You still have to parse the template source to find the offending tag. Does Jinja2 provide any parsing API? Otherwise you'll have to reimplement it, which is not good.

Comment: Yes. Jinja has a parsing API. Finding the blocks in the parent template is very easy : template = env.from_string(content_to_save) followed : by for each in template.blocks .... And if you cannot define a block, you cannot extend it.

Comment: Wow, that sounds great. Care to provide a short example in your answer? I guess this would be useful to the OP as well as for others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11129/discussion-between-helgi-and-voscausa)